# Compare between two dates with time and timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

I am developing a login functionality, where user is not allowed to login between some duration of time, and this is configurable.
For example user is not allowed to login between

```
 {
  "fromDate": "2022-03-08",
  "toDate": 2022-03-15,
  "fromTime": "09:00",
  "toTime": "16:00",
  "timezone": "Canada/Toronto", 
  "days": [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help in comparing fromDate and toDate with current User login time.
I am tryin to convert all dates in UTC and then compare.
As user can login anywhere so as per login time date may change in other country.
Any suggestions/reference would be helpful.

Comment: Provided an answer please consider to upvote and approve as answer if it satisfy the requirement otherwise feel free to comment below it.

Comment: Your example data looks like common business hours when users *would* be allowed to log in, not forbidden to log in. And you are missing quotes on second date.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a schoolwork assignment. So I’ll give a brief outline of the needed code, and let you fill in the details.

Parse your [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) into Java objects.

In the Java ecosystem, you have a choice of frameworks to assist in parsing JSON. These include [Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API)) and [Jakarta EE](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/november/jsonjakartaee.php).

You need to end up with objects of the *java.time* classes as shown in code here.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse( "2022-03-08" ) ;
…
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse( "09:00" ) ;
…
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Canada/Toronto" ) ;
Set< DayOfWeek > dows = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class ) ;
dows.add( DayOfWeek.valueOf( "Monday".toUppercase() ) ;
…
```

Capture the current moment as seen with an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-days.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Adjust into target [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Interrogate for the parts of that moment.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

[Compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) to your limits.

```
if( ( ! ld.isBefore( startDate ) ) && ld.isBefore( endDate )  ) { … }
…
if( dows.contains( dow ) { … }
```

Regarding comparisons, I suggest you learn about Half-Closed versus Fully-Closed. I recommend consistent use of Half-Closed.

All these topics have been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

One practice is to use **ZonedDateTime** and put the zone at **UTC** or compare the **offsetDateTime**

```html
    LocalDateTime ldtLowerBound = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-03-08T9:00:00");
    LocalDateTime ldtUpperBound = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-03-15T6:00:00");

    //For zonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldtLowerBound.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    //For OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime odt = ldtLowerBound.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Then compare them with user localDateTime with your desired logic.

Comment: See more in here.  https://mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/